# Give #Hom$(D_n,G)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite commutative group with uneven order, and $n \in \mathbb{Z_\geq3}$ uneven.  Give #Hom$(D_n,G)$.

I'm studying for an exam but every time these sort of questions seem different, can anyone  give me the idea?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then all homomorphisms into $G$ kill the commutator subgroup.  So you really only need to count homomorphisms from the abelianization of $D_n$ into $G$.

Comment: What is $D_n/\[D_n,D_n\]$ exactly?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then the abelianization is $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  To see this let $\sigma,\tau$ be generators of $D_n$ satisfying $\sigma^n=1$, $\tau^2=1$ and $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^-{1}$.  Then $\sigma^2=\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}$, so $\sigma^2$ lies in the commutator subgroup.  Since $\sigma^n=1$ for some odd $n$, $\sigma$ is a power of $\sigma^2$.  Hence $\sigma\in[D_n,D_n]$.  Since $\sigma$ maps to the identity in $D_n/[D_n,D_n]$, $D_n/[D_n,D_n]$ is generated solely by $\tau$, and has order at most 2.  To show it is nontrivial you can construct a homomorphism from $D_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2$